# c# console current input value

Tags: c#, console

Is there any way to get a current input value before the user actually sends the input?

Imagine I have a menu in a console which looks somewhat like this:

> You are currently in MenuTitle
>   Please enter a data in the following manner: [Date], [Title], [Description]
>   ==== Here the user types the message ===

The issue is that this menu that is currently ongoing MAY and SHOULD change when an event occurs. So technically we're being kicked out of the current menu and redirected to another menu, even while the user is currently typing his data.

What I would like to accomplish is to gather whatever the user has already typed in so let's say, the user already managed to type in:

07/07/2018, This is my title, This is -------- BOOM here we kick him out of the menu to make an important decision about something else. I would like to somehow get this: "07/07/2018, This is my title, This is" - into some kind of variable to use it later when the user already makes an important decision and finally goes back to the menu he was in before (which is the one he was typing the message in).

Possible? Cannot even come up with any keywords to google it neither...

Comment: Maybe Console.ReadKey in a while loop and then process each keystroke at a time.

Comment: Was hoping for the entire string but if nobody answers in couple of minutes feel free to post this as an answer and i'll mark it. I haven't got any other idea.

Comment: Just append each key to a variable outside the scope of the while loop until the key == enter or if it == backspace then remove the last character from the string.

Comment: Ye man go ahead post this so I can mark your answer, once i thought of it deeper i don't think there exists a way to gather the entire string all at once...

Comment: I think you need to rethink the design. What you are describing Sounds very odd and seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I do not believe this is an XY problem. What kind of approach would you have in mind over this issue. In my case X and Y are completely unrelated. It's not that the use is being kicked out of his current menu just because he had anything to do with it. It's just that a clock is counting time and the time has just arrived to inform the user about something super important.